# Project Euler Even Fibonacci

Tags: java

I'm interested in the shortest solution for the project Euler's second problem: Even Fibonacci numbers in Java.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>   1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>   By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the 
>   sum of the even-valued terms.

What I have at the moment:

```
public class fibonnaci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int f=0,t=0,n=0,s=1;
    for(;n<4000000;n=f+s){
        f=s;s=n;
        if(n%2==0)t+=n;
    }
    System.out.println(t);
   }
}
```

I added spaces for readability.

How can I make this shorter (or correct in case it isn't)?

Comment: *"How can I make this shorter"*  Good code is not so much 'short' as 1) Efficient in use of memory and CPU cycles 2) Extensible & maintainable by other programmers.  It might be a 'computer language' but the bulk of it is intended for human eyes.  'Clear and understandable' is therefore arguably better than 'lowest char count'.

Comment: Shorter: you don't need the '&&n<l' (because n=f+s is evaluated after the body of the for loop)

Comment: To extend on what Andrew said, more descriptive variables names would definitely be a plus.

Comment: I know but this is intended only for me and it is only supposed to be as short as possible, I mean with the least possible amount of characters.

Comment: If you want short code, try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I noticed it is actually shorter to explicitly declare the f,t and n.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution to this would probably be to create an array of Fibonnaci number. Create a loop with a counter. At least iteration, calculate the next number and push it onto the array. Keep in mind that since F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), and you will already have F(n-1),F(n-2) calculated and saved, this will be a simple addition. If this number exceeds your limit, exit the loop.

Now iterate through the array adding every other number (which will be the even ones).

This would probably be your most efficient use of CPU.

**Update:** As C. Lang (indirectly) pointed out, you could maintain the sum as you calculate through to avoid having to iterate through the list at the end.

Comment: I think he just wants to print them. Why save the ones you don't need? It wouldn't be best to just iterate and print if needed?

Comment: Because by saving them he does not need to recursively recalculate them when finding F(n+1), F(n+2), ... etc. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: The fib example in your link is pulling the nth fib. My point, relative to the example supplied, is that you still have to calculate the numbers in order to store them. There's no doubt additional costs in storing the data, half of which you don't need, then you traverse the array again to print it.

Comment: I honestly didn't know there was a Fib example in the link, I was just showing you Dynamic Programming. The point of a dynamic programming solution is that you only have to calculate each F(n) ONCE, instead of repeatedly for each proceeding number.

Comment: +1 for effort and defense. I agree with your overall point in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you think `public static void main(String[]a) {System.out.println(4613732);}` *cheating*, how about not messing with odd values?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int f,s,t=s=2,n=8;
    for(;n<4000000;t+=n,f=s,s=n,n=f+4*s);
    System.out.println(t);
}
```